# How to pull all user sharing activity using the Activity API inside App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apis-explorer

I am new to Google API and got training wheels on for the App Script.

I need to know if there is a way to utilize the Activity API or any other inside App Script to pull sharing activity for all domain users.

Thanks in advance.

I got the following working for me but it is not showing me the "shared_externally" in particular, I need to use https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list api for all users on drive app, externally and internally shared filter.

```
function listShares() {
var userKey = 'all';
var applicationName = 'drive';
var optionalArgs = {
visibility: 'shared_externally'
};
var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, 
optionalArgs)
Logger.log(response);
}
```

My output is the same with or without the optionalArgs for shared_externally, can someone help with the proper syntax for the visibility arguments?

Comment: It sounds like this question is relevant to the "google-apps-script" tag.

Comment: its relevant to both api and app script. just edited.

Comment: I am not sure why my question got voted down for not doing enough research, i have been researching on my own and couldn't find an answer therefore posted here for help. In the API i linked I am able to use the API on the browser to see the results, but it does not give an example for the request other than a HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it to work, yay.

```
function listShares() {
var userKey = 'all';
var applicationName = 'drive';
var optionalArgs = {
filters: 'visibility==shared_externally'
};
var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, 
optionalArgs)
Logger.log(response);}
```